# Apache - How to Ignore Paths and Paramaters in 301 Redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, httpd, 301-redirect

Say I want all requests to example.com to redirect to abc.com.

How can I make everything redirect to the root of abc.com and not include any paths or parameters included in example.com?

For example

```
example.com/index.py?var=1 should go to abc.com
```

I tried this in my .htaccess

```
RedirectPermanent / http://www.abc.com
```

But it does this:

```
example.com/index.py?var=1 goes to abc.com/index.py?var=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following redirect:

```
RedirectMatch permanent . http://www.abc.com
```